# Dataframe issue with NetworkD3 in R

Tags: r, d3.js, networkd3

I'm getting a

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(Links, , Source) : undefined columns selected
```

when I try to plot a network using the `forceNetwork` function in `NetworkD3`.

My dataframes look like the following:

```
> head(linkDf)
  Source Target
1     25      1
2     83      1
3     83      2
4     42      3
5     26      4
6     25      4
```

and

```
 > head(nodeDf2)     
         name group size
    1    A     1    2
    2    B     1    1
    3    C     2    1
    4    D     3    2
    5    E     2    2
    6    F     1    1
```

I'm trying to plot the network using the following function:

```
forceNetwork(Links = linkDf, Nodes = nodeDf2,
              Source = linkDf$Source, Target = linkDf$Target,
              NodeID = nodeDf2$name,
              Group = nodeDf2$group, opacity = 0.8)
```

All the columns have data in them, and I'm not sure why R tells me that I'm selecting undefined columns.

Answer (score 0):

The values passed to the `Source`, `Target`, `Value`, `NodeID`, and `Group` arguments should be **strings** that correspond to the name of the columns in your `Links` and `Nodes` data frames that contain the corresponding data... not the actual columns/vectors. So change your example too...

```
forceNetwork(Links = linkDf, Nodes = nodeDf2, Source = "Source", 
             Target = "Target", NodeID = "name", Group = "group", 
             opacity = 0.8)
```